# I have to provide the argument arr twice, once in Sorting(arr) and again in quicksort(arr), How can I rewrite the code using arr only once?

Tags: python, class, recursion

```
class Sorting:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr
        n = len(arr)

    def quicksort(self,arr):
        if len(arr) <= 1:
            return arr

        else:
            pivot = arr[0]
            del arr[0]

            items_greater = []
            items_lower = []
            for item in arr:
                if item > pivot:
                    items_greater.append(item)
                else:
                    items_lower.append(item)

            return sor.quicksort(items_lower) + [pivot] + sor.quicksort(items_greater)




arr = [4,3,2,1,-5,-89,10]
n = len(arr)
sor = Sorting(arr)
print(sor.quicksort(arr))
```

> Output: [-89, -5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 10]

**I have to provide the argument arr twice, once in Sorting(arr) and again in quicksort(arr), How can I rewrite the code using arr only once ?**

Comment: `return sor.quicksort` is gonna explode right in your face. use `self` (`return self.quicksort`)

Comment: @diggusbickus: While `self.quicksort(...` is undoubtable the correct code to write (I didn't see this mistake until you commented), I tried the code and it didn't '*explode*'. (lol great username btw)

Comment: it didn't explode now because the instance is named `sor` but if you need two instances or simply naming it how you want, please take a shield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `arr` an optional argument, and use `self.arr` when it's not provided. You only need to pass it explicitly in the recursive calls.

```
class Sorting:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr
        n = len(arr)

    def quicksort(self, arr = None):
        if arr is None:
            arr = self.arr

        if len(arr) <= 1:
            return arr

        else:
            pivot = arr[0]
            del arr[0]

            items_greater = []
            items_lower = []
            for item in arr:
                if item > pivot:
                    items_greater.append(item)
                else:
                    items_lower.append(item)

            return sor.quicksort(items_lower) + [pivot] + sor.quicksort(items_greater)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the `__init__()` method:

```py
class Sorting:
    def quicksort(self,arr):
        if len(arr) <= 1:
            return arr

        else:
            pivot = arr[0]
            del arr[0]

            items_greater = []
            items_lower = []
            for item in arr:
                if item > pivot:
                    items_greater.append(item)
                else:
                    items_lower.append(item)

            return self.quicksort(items_lower) + [pivot] + self.quicksort(items_greater)

arr = [4,3,2,1,-5,-89,10]

sor = Sorting()
print(sor.quicksort(arr))
```

Same output as before.